# Variables in Crontab Amazon Linux

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Can't get crontabs with variables working on Amazon Linux. It's weird cause those variables do work in the command line of the system, but won't work inside the cronjob. I know the variables are the problem, cause when I remove the part from `--args`till `>`, the cronjob will be executed.

Worked fine on Ubuntu:

```
0 7 * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/cronjob.py --method all --args $(date -d "1 day ago" +%Y%m%d),$(date +%Y%m%d) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Also tried:

```
47 16 * * * python /path/to/cronjob.py --method all --args `date -d "1 day ago" +%Y%m%d`,`date +%Y%m%d` > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Did you look for error messages in `/var/log/cron` ?

Comment: this isn't a python/AWS issue; [here's an answer+explanation on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/84430/whats-wrong-with-my-cronjob-syntax-im-trying-to-use-a-backtick).

Comment: Thank you very much @tedder42, the backslashes before the % fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tedder42 solution worked for me, I only needed to add the backslashes before the %:

```
47 16 * * * python /path/to/cronjob.py --method all --args `date -d "1 day ago" +\%Y\%m\%d`,`date +\%Y\%m\%d` > /dev/null 2>&1
```